# Jquery : Use the plugin jquery validate to stop a Click after just Clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the plugin Jquery validate on simple form , my sketch is that :

1- Am clicking a first button

2- i m filling a form in a pop-up (i'm setting required aninput text named **"montant"**

3- to validate i would click on button **(which is a simple one , it's a not with type=submit)**

4-Normally , when i clicking this second button without filling my required input , the click would be **aborted/ stoped** which is not in fact my case

***My View Form :***

```
<form class="clearfix" id="form-candidature" method="post" action="api/condidaturepostulers">
       <h4 class="modal__subtitle">Postuler</h4>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 field">
         <label class="field-label">Montant: *</label>
         <input  class="field-input" name="montant" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 field">
          <label class="field-label field-label--textarea">Message de motivation :</label>
          <textarea class="field-input field-input--textarea" name="msgMotivation"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 txtright">
            <input id="submitCandidature" class="btn action-form btn-validate" value="Valider" data-modal="modal-validate">
            <input class="btn btn--gray action-form" type="button" value="Annuler" data-close="modal">
         </div>
</form>
```

***In My Javascipt file:***

*1 - First of all i'm wrinting a fonction of my form validation :*

```
candidatureValidate: function () {   
            $("form[id='form-candidature']").validate({
                rules: {
                    montant: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    montant: "Veuillez entrer un montant"
                },

            })
  }
```

*2- After that i'm making an initialization of that function with the initi of my page :*

```
init: function () {
            for (var i in annonce.page) {
                if (annonce.page[i].length) {
                    this.candidatureValidate();
                    this.postulate();  // my principal funtion

                }
            }
},
```

*3- In my principal function (postulate () ) , im calling my validation function :*

```
postulate: function () {
            $('body').one().on('click', '#submitCandidature', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var FormCandidature = $("#form-candidature");
                var candidatureObject = serializeObject(FormCandidature);
                if (FormCandidature.valid()){
                    console.log(candidatureObject);
                    window.sendData.start(FormCandidature, candidatureObject, "#modal-postuler");
                }else {
                    e.stop();  // THis doesn't work
                }

   },
```

**Any suggestions ???**

Comment: Your form is already have action tag and in postulate function instead of click event try with type="submit" with formID and then preventDefault action ...

Comment: Your issue is still somewhat unclear.  If you've initialized the plugin properly, the form submit is already blocked by default.  Since you're not using a `type="submit"`, you merely put a `.valid()` inside a `click` handler and again, any form errors would block the submission.

Answer (score 0):

use e.stopPropagation() function instead of e.stop()

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
$('body').one().on('click', '#submitCandidature', function (e) { ...
```

Use `.on()` **OR** use `.one()`.  There is no situation where you'd be able to chain these together.  Nor is there any scenario where you can leave `.one()` empty.

As per the [jQuery `.one()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

> The `.one()` method **is identical** to `.on()`, except that the handler for a given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation.

Try this instead...

```
$('body').one('click', '#submitCandidature', function (e) { ...
```